# Getting coordinates of individual polygon in shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile, coordinates, features, pyshp

I just started working with shapefiles. I need to take polygon # 93 (Sea of ​​Japan) in a large shapefile and build a sea map in bokeh Python.
How do I refer to a specific polygon in a shapefile?

```py
import shapefile

shape = shapefile.Reader("С:/World_Seas_IHO_v3.shp") # There are 101 polygons in total, the polygon I need is 93
#first feature of the shapefile
feature = shape.shapeRecords()[0]
first = feature.shape.__geo_interface__  
print(first) #
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result is a dictionary ([GeoJSON format](https://geojson.org/), see [Python Geo_interface applications](https://github.com/mlaloux/Python-geo_interface-applications) for example)

```
import shapefile
r = shapefile.Reader("polys.shp")
rec = r.shapeRecords()[7]
geom = rec.shape.__geo_interface__
print(geom) # GeoJSON format)
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(245402.24387797402, 1000578.2015550972), (245597.81746161517, 1000599.6342765922), (245640.682904605, 1000453.623861408), (245395.54615250687, 1000450.9447712211), (245402.24387797402, 1000578.2015550972)]]}
# therefore
coords = geom['coordinates'] # or directly rec.shape.__geo_interface__['coordinates']
print(coords)
[[(245402.24387797402, 1000578.2015550972), (245597.81746161517, 1000599.6342765922), (245640.682904605, 1000453.623861408), (245395.54615250687, 1000450.9447712211), (245402.24387797402, 1000578.2015550972)]]
```

#### New

```
for i in coords[0]:
    print(i)

(245402.24387797402, 1000578.2015550972)
(245597.81746161517, 1000599.6342765922)
(245640.682904605, 1000453.623861408)
(245395.54615250687, 1000450.9447712211)
(245402.24387797402, 1000578.2015550972)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also get your points simply via [`points`](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp#reading-geometry):

> The points attribute contains a list of tuples containing an (x,y)
> coordinate for each point in the shape.

```py
import shapefile

shape = shapefile.Reader("C:/TempData/test/grids.shp")

feature = shape.shapeRecords()[0]

points = feature.shape.points
print(points)
```

That results in

```
[(413795.5781, 5655831.7174), (413895.5781, 5655831.7174), (413895.5781, 5655731.7174), (413795.5781, 5655731.7174), (413795.5781, 5655831.7174)]
```

Also with this method one can refer to a specific point of a feature:

```py
point2 = feature.shape.points[2] # vertex #2
print(point2)
```

will give you

```
(413895.5781, 5655731.7174)
```